# How to catch process being blocked by outbound iptables fw?

Tags: iptables, firewall, process

**NOTE**: Thanks for suggesting answers. I'm having a look at them but the main issue (as stated below) is that **outbound** iptables hide information from tools like `netstat` and `auditd`. I need to look at `stap` though (and I can't open the firewall to experiment, I'm afraid).

---

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server on which an `iptables` firewall is dropping intermittent outbound connections on port 80 to disallowed IP addresses.

How do I tell what process is attempting the connections? I have read [iptable block outbound traffic for which binary?](https://serverfault.com/questions/722988/iptable-block-outbound-traffic-for-which-binary) and created a script that runs the relevant lookups when blocks occur in the logs.

But as far as I can tell, `fuser` and `netstat` aren't showing the connections to the IPs being logged - they only seem to show connections that are not being blocked (I think this [may be expected behaviour](https://serverfault.com/questions/233302/will-tcpdump-see-packets-that-are-being-dropped-by-iptables) for outbound `iptables` rules).

Comment: Example of output captured with auditd, despite firewalled: `iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 5555`.  `auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a2=1 -S sendto -k SENDTO` to trace any sendto having only 1-byte payload. Run `echo '' | socat udp4-sendto:192.0.2.2:5554 -` (=> success) and `echo '' | socat udp4-sendto:192.0.2.2:5555 -` (=> EPERM). Use `ausearch -i -ts today -k SENDTO  |grep socat` and witness both are captured. One with `success=yes exit=1` and one with `success=no exit=EPERM(Operation not permitted)` (if auditd.conf includes `log_format = ENRICHED`): so auditd does capture both.

Comment: For TCP you'd probably have to capture connect().